# How to handle play store alpha/beta test if you have multiple product flavours (different remote server instance)

Tags: android, gradle, google-play

I have an app which needs go through the following development stage

Develop-> SIT->UAT->LIVE

each stage has own remote server

```
Develop (https://www.xyz-dev.environment.com)
SIT (https://www.xyz-sit.environment.com)
UAT(https://www.xyz-uat.environment.com)
Live(https://www.xyz.environment.com)
```

i have used product flavours as below

```
android {
        compileSdkVersion ...
        buildToolsVersion ...


     buildTypes {
         release {
                minifyEnabled true
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
          }

         debug {
                applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
          }
      }

  productFlavors {

           dev{
            applicationId "com.myapp.dev"
              buildConfigField("String", "ENV", "http://xyz-dev.environment.com")
           } 

          sit {
            applicationId "com.myapp.sit"
            buildConfigField("String", "ENV", "http://xyz-sit.environment.com")
          }


          uat {
            applicationId "com.myapp.uat"
            buildConfigField("String", "ENV", "http://xyz-uat.environment.com")

          }

          prod {
            applicationId "com.myapp"
            buildConfigField("String", "ENV", "http://xyz.environment.com")

          }
        }
    }
```

I'm confused how to use Play store alpha/Beta test? if I upload a SIT flavour apk to alpha and promote to beta and production it will point to SIT env?

I can build a prod release version and upload to alpha and then promote to beta and production? but the problem here is users will modify production data

I don't want alpa/beta test users to modify production data and hit prod server? also they should be able to run both prod app and beta app side by side?

what is the best way to handle alpa/beta test pointing different env ?

Comment: the flavour which u will release will be in effect

Answer (score 1):

Answering Your queries one by one :

if I upload a SIT flavour apk to alpha and promote to beta and production it will point to SIT env?

```
Yes it will point to SIT URL.
```

I can build a prod release version and upload to alpha and then promote to beta and production?

```
 yes u need to make sure that data is not modified from server side until u move that into production.
```

I don't want alpa/beta test users to modify production data and hit prod server? also they should be able to run both prod app and beta app side by side?

```
Not possible because application package will be same
```

what is the best way to handle alpa/beta test pointing different env ?

```
Build Apk's with separate flavours for each to the respective environments u want to point and maintain different version codes for each otherwise it would never accept ur apk.
```